# How to get Value and Index number of tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

```
preds = model([img_feat, ques_feat])
sorted_a = tf.sort(preds, direction='DESCENDING')
print(sorted_a[0][1])
```

It will print `tf.Tensor(0.35625213, shape=(), dtype=float32)`.

Here I just need the number 0.35625213 and its index.

Comment: Add more details and a reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

To print the value, you can convert the tensor to numpy and then print it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# defining a float tensor
a = tf.constant(2.34)

# print tensor
print(a)              # output: tf.Tensor(2.34, shape=(), dtype=float32)

# convert to numpy and then print
print(a.numpy())      # output: 2.34
```

Comment: how do i get Index number in this form
tf.Tensor([962], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)

Comment: User ``tf.argsort`` instead of ``tf.sort`` to get the index.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort

@ShahidkhanM